# Add "Select All'' button to ion-select

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using ionic 4 and I want to set custom buttons on ion-select through interfaceOptions

HTML

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Lines</ion-label>
  <ion-select multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="SelectedLines" [interfaceOptions]="customAlertOptions">
    <ion-select-option [value]="line" *ngFor="let line of Lines">{{linea.Name}}</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

TS

```
customAlertOptions: any = {
buttons: [
  {
    text: 'Select All',
    handler: (blah) => {
      console.log('Select All Clicked');
    },
  {
    text: 'No',
    handler: (blah) => {
      console.log('Confirm Cancel: blah');
    }
  }, {
    text: 'Okay',
    handler: () => {
      console.log('Confirm Okay');
    }
  }
]
```

};

However, only the default buttons are showing (Ok and Cancel)

Docs say it should be possible

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select

I can see this has been reported for previous versions of Ionic

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/custom-button-for-ion-select-through-selectoptions-not-working/157305

Is it possible to make this work on Ionic 4? Is there a workaround?

EDIT: I tried with the PopOver interface with the same results

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do isn't possible from what I can see.

The documentation actually only says you can set the buttons text:

- [ion-select#select-buttons - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#select-buttons)

> By default, the alert has two buttons: `Cancel` and `OK`. Each button's text can be customized using the `cancelText` and `okText` properties.

It doesn't say that the buttons can be customised.

You can pass in the `interfaceOptions` but its overridden later by the default button set:

- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/select/select.tsx#L339

The code looks like this:

```
const alertOpts: AlertOptions = {
  mode,
  ...interfaceOptions,

  header: interfaceOptions.header ? interfaceOptions.header : labelText,
  inputs: this.createAlertInputs(this.childOpts, inputType),
  buttons: [
    {
      text: this.cancelText,
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: () => {
        this.ionCancel.emit();
      }
    },
    {
      text: this.okText,
      handler: (selectedValues: any) => {
        this.value = selectedValues;
      }
    }
  ],
  cssClass: ['select-alert', interfaceOptions.cssClass,
             (this.multiple ? 'multiple-select-alert' : 'single-select-alert')]
};
return alertController.create(alertOpts);
```

So as you can see the `...interfaceOptions,` is passed in at the start, then the buttons are set to the defaults, with the only customisation options being the ok or cancel text.

Comment: Thanks, Is there like a "popular" workaround? I was thinking something like copy the whole component from the code in Github to my project and modify it there, avoiding that override

Comment: It's something that I have become curious about but not tried yet. A lot of questions are people trying to do things where they are bumping up against whats supported. The move to web components gave a lot of positives but the tough part about it is that if the component doesnt support it out of the box you can't tweak it because its insides are hidden from view when on the page. I would be interested to know how difficult it is to extract a single component from Ionic core.

Answer (score 0):

i am working with AlertController from ionic and i can custom it, just take a look at [my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dniWU.png) .

You just need to import AlertController and after you can do something like this for exemple :

**home.page.ts**

```
async addAlertHome(adresse: string, lat: string, lon: string) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Ajouter aux favoris',
      message: 'Êtes vous sûr de vouloir ajouter cette adresse à vos favoris ?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Non',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary'
        }, {
          text: 'Oui',
          handler: () => {
            alert.dismiss().then(() => {
              this.addFavoriteHome(adresse, lat, lon);
            });
            console.log('Confirm Okay');

          }
        }
      ]
    });


    await alert.present();
  }
```

And use it where you want on html :
**home.page.html**

```
<ion-icon name="heart-empty" (click)="addAlert(location.display_name, location.lat, location.lon)" end>
            </ion-icon>
```

And don't forget on your constructor :

```
public alertController: AlertController
```

Comment: Yes, it should work right?. But it doesn't for ion-select

Comment: Yes, it is working, but i think is more complexe with ion-select its why i propose an alternative !

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this is not alternative, I need an ion-select, it needs to contain items, this is just an alert, of couse I could implement something like [this](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-how-to-select-all-unselect-all-checkboxes-with-ideterminate-in-ionic-4/), it looks good, and I will use it if I have no other options.